# Docker container Xdebug (php-fpm) - There was a problem sending 179 bytes on socket 6: Broken pipe

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, xdebug-3

I am trying to set up Xdebug 3 in a docker container and capture a break point in Visual Studio Code.

My xdebug log:

```
[7] Log opened at 2021-02-16 16:12:12.027862
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking remote connect back address.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 172.26.0.1:9099.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.26.0.1:9099 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header). :-)
[7] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.27" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.0.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[7] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[7] [Step Debug] WARN: 2021-02-16 16:12:12.039287: There was a problem sending 179 bytes on socket 6: Broken pipe.
```

xdebug.ini configuration:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.client_port = 9099
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
xdebug.log = /var/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Visual Studio Code configuration (json.config)

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9099,
            "log": true,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/public": "${workspaceFolder}",
            },
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I will be grateful for your help, I have run out of ideas why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

host.docker.internal - mac only

**172.17.0.1**/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0

probably

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.idekey = "VSCODE"
```

Comment: host.docker.internal also works for Windows